# Getting past [Authorize] attribute without being logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using **.net core Identity UI**.

At first, I could not access the [Authorize] actions despite being logged in. I searched day and night for the solution and found it -> I simply added

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

in Configure method in **Startup.cs**. However, no I can access my actions without actually being logged in. I made sure I logged out at *identity/acccount/logout*.

I really don't know if any code paste is required but I'll provide if deemed necessary.

edit code:
Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using lalalala.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace lalalala
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

action I can access without being logged in:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("MemeId, Tags, Name, File")] Meme meme)
        {

            Account account = new Account(
             "***",
             "***",
             "***");
            var cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await meme.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    meme.Buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(meme.Buffer, 0, meme.Buffer.Length);
                    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(meme.File.FileName, ms)
                    };

                    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                    meme.Url = uploadResult.Uri.ToString();
                }





                _context.Add(meme);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(meme);
        }
```

Comment: Yes. Please add the code.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged out? The `[Authorize]` attribute validates the authentication cookie. Check the Storage/Cookies area of your browser for the presence of a cookie `.ASPXAUTH` - if that is still there, you're still logged in. You can manually delete the cookie to force a logout.

Comment: @chicken head ,  1. Could you please make a breakpoint on the action method protected by `[Authorize]` , and take a look at the current User along with the cookies sent by browser ? 2.  If possible ,  source code of a minimal project , which is able to reproduce the same issue ,  will make the debug faster .